# Не отображается часть дат на графике в chart

Tags: c#, winforms

Загружаю файл, из него беру даты и значения для построения графика.

```
public void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        chart1.Series[0].Points.Clear();
        fail = openFileDialog.FileName;
        string[] dtz = File.ReadAllLines(fail); 
    for (int i = 0; i < dtz.Length - 1; i += 2)
            chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(dtz[i], dtz[i + 1]);
    }
}
```

По итогу получаю график:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так чтобы все даты отображались?